# Is/Was Amalek Justified in Causing Suffering?

Tags: amalek

The Talmud in Sanhedrin (99b) states:

> בעיא לאיגיורי באתה אצל אברהם יצחק ויעקב ולא קבלוה הלכה והיתה פילגש
> לאליפז בן עשו אמרה מוטב תהא שפחה לאומה זו ולא תהא גבירה לאומה אחרת נפק
> מינה עמלק דצערינהו לישראל מאי טעמא דלא איבעי להו לרחקה
>
> Timna sought to convert. She came before Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob,
> and they did not accept her. She went and became a concubine of
> Eliphaz, son of Esau, and said, referring to herself: It is preferable
> that she will be a maidservant for this nation, and she will not be a
> noblewoman for another nation. Ultimately, Amalek, son of Eliphaz,
> emerged from her, and that tribe afflicted the Jewish people. What is
> the reason that the Jewish people were punished by suffering at the
> hand of Amalek? It is due to the fact that they should not have
> rejected her when she sought to convert.

Per this Talmudic piece, since Yisrael "struck the first blow," Amalek is/was 'justified' in causing Jewish suffering.

And yet we have a mitzva to destroy Amalek. Is this because of the suffering they cause? If so, what gives?

Comment: Does refusing to let someone convert give them justification to becoming one's mortal enemy?

Comment: Some other interesting tidbits I came across: 1) The [Diqduqe Soferim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38520&st=&pgnum=309&hilite=) states that the phase מאי טעמא דלא איבעי להו לרחקה is not found in early manuscripts. 2) The [Midrash Tanhuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Vayeshev.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that Timna was a mamzereth. 3) [Gen. Rabbah 39:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.39.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states that Sarah was responsible for converting women, which sounds like a contradiction to this Gemara.

Comment: https://aish.com/107936749/

Comment: "My significant other broke things off for no good reason, so I firebombed his house." Relatable vis-a-vis human nature? Yes. Justified? No.

Comment: @ Shalom. Thx. Yes ... maybe Amalek's method is the problem.

Comment: @Shalom claiming it is "understandable" calls into question the extreme "punishment" Hashem meted out to Amalek (annihilation)